# Memory addresses are shown instead of values?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I've been using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 since it was initially released and been able to see the value of my local Members and Fields just like you traditionally would when debugging a .net app. Today however, I noticed I no longer see the values, rather I believe I'm seeing the memory address, or a hex value.

[image]

What would have changed to cause this? How do I get it back to the default settings so that I can see the real value on the Members?

Comment: And why do you think a hex value is a memory address? It just is a hex value - which is a setting you can set (right click) and usefull in some (rare) scenarios when you actually deal with hex constants in code etc. I see no memory address at all anywhere.

Comment: Honestly, because I write managed code all day, everyday and not any unmanaged code were in exposed to memory addresses all the time. I don't think I've ever actually seen what a memory address looks like, so there was confusion on my part as to what that value represented

Comment: Hex is used a lot when you deal for example with flag enums. Some of us can easily read hex values to their binary representation (heck, only 16 values) - this is a lot harder with decimal ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the value and remove `Hex` display check

[image]